# modify jquery datatable automatically instead of on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery datatable which allows me to modify cells onclick using this function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('td').click(function () { 
         var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
         var aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos[0]);
         var retrievedEntry = aData[aPos[1]];
         this.innerHTML = '10'; 
     });

     oTable = $('#myHTMLTable').dataTable();
 });
```

however what i would like to be able to do is to modify the contents of a column based on the entries in the cells of other columns. So if i have "name" and "age" column, if the name == "John" then update age cell data to 10 and if name == "Mike" then update age to say 11;

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try keyup or keydown events assuming the update process will involve data entry.

Comment: hi and thanks for you quick reply. Can you help elaborate on how I may use that to achieve what i need? maybe an example? Thanks

Comment: its an event well documented in the jquery documentation. Basically element.keyup(function(){etc}) - a bit like the click event you are currently using